# How to gzip next js 12 app hosted on vercel

Tags: next.js, gzip, vercel

Hello everyone I recently deployed a next js blog with SSR. I use WordPress and wp graphql for data and my question is how to gzip the whole next js app because according to pingdom my page size is around 800Kb and 400 of them are js.

I also add compress true to next.config.js

My app is hosted on vercel

Thanks for your time in advance

Comment: Using `compress: true` will compress rendered content and static files. Are you sure your app's files are not getting compressed (check the `Content-Encoding` header on each file's request)?